# Resources (advice and recipes) for sour beers

Tags: sour

I've decided to start a program of creating sour beers where every 3 months I'll brew a new sour beer and set up a closet for aging of the beers.  Given the length of the process and the amount I brew, I'm going to explore a spectrum versus trying to nail down one recipe and be able to repeat it.

What are some good sources for recipes and techniques for sour beers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to home brewing sours [The Mad Fermentationist](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/) should be your first stop. His blog is quite large, and full of great information. His [intro to brewing sours](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2009/11/brewing-sour-beer-at-home.html) is probably the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Wild Brews, by Jeff Sparrow has a whole lot of information about how the pros do it, and has a few recipes in the back of the book, which look interesting, but I haven't tried.

Yeast, by Chris White & Jamil Zainasheff has a couple of sections on Brettanomyces, which might prove useful.